# laravel blade view templating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, templating, laravel-blade

This is  `$reviewDetails`

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [userId] => 1
        [activityId] => 20
        [reviewId] => 6
        [title] => 
        [description] => 
        [rating] => 4
        [userName] => abcd
        [userCity] => wwqqwe
        [profilePicture] => 
        [reviewDate] => 2017-00-09 
        [images] => 
        [status] => 1
   )
   [1] => stdClass Object (
       [userId] => 78
       [activityId] => 20
       [reviewId] => 33
       [title] => Star trek
       [description] => nice trek
       [rating] => 4
       [userName] => abcd
       [userCity] => 
       [profilePicture] => MTQ4OTUwOTYzOS43OA==
       [reviewDate] => 2017-03-11 12:19:39
       [images] => Array (
           [0] => stdClass Object (
               [title] => my click
               [file] => MTQ4OTIzNDcwNy42OA==
           )
           [1] => stdClass Object (
               [title] => my click
               [file] => MTQ4OTIzNDczMi4xMQ==
           )
       )
       [status] => 0
    )
)
```

reviews.blade.php file

```
@foreach ($reviewDetails as $reviewDetail)
    @if (! empty($reviewDetail->images))
        @foreach ($reviewDetail->images as $reviewImage)
            <p>
                <img src="{{ $reviewImage->file }}">
            </p>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>No image</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

this code doesnt work in laravel and it shows trying to get property of non-object ??
How can i display images array in blade template ....please help

Answer (score 1):

You've missed a $ in your foreach loop. Additionally, the `<img>` tag was not being closed in the HTML.

```
@foreach($reviewDetails as $reviewDetail)
    @if(!empty($reviewDetail->images))
        @foreach($reviewDetail->images as $reviewImage)
            <p><img src="{{$reviewImage->file}}"></p>
        @endforeach
    @else
         <p>No image</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that the `<img>` tag isn't properly closed.